# Creación de una función recursiva

Tags: array, c

Busco su ayuda para poder resolver un problema de la universidad que la verdad no logro entender, el problema me pide que haga un programa que haga 2 cosas:

1. Sacar el factorial de un numero ingresado por el usuario **(esta parte ya esta resuelta)**
2. Sumar los "n" números que ingrese el usuario utilizando la recursión.

En la segunda parte es donde estoy muy perdido, hasta el momento entiendo que lo que debo hacer es crear un arreglo en el que el usuario ingrese cuantos números quiere sumar y después ingrese el valor de esos números para que se guarden dentro del arreglo, aquí dejo el código que llevo hasta el momento:

```
long factorial (int x);
int suma ();

int main ()
{
    int opcion = 0;
    int sizeofarrey = 0;
    int arrey [sizeofarrey];
    int i=0;
    int n=0;
    int y=0;
    
    printf ("Selecciona la opcion deseada: \n");
    printf ("Opcion 1 = Factorial \n");
    printf ("Opcion 2 = Sumar \n");
    scanf ("%i",&opcion);
    
    if (opcion == 1){
        
        printf ("Ingresa el numero a factorizar ");
        scanf ("%i",&y);
        printf ("El resultado es %li", factorial(y));
    }
    
    if (opcion == 2){
        
        printf ("Cuantos numeros quieres ingresar?\n");
        scanf ("%i",&sizeofarrey);
        printf ("La cantidad de numeros a ingresar es %i \n", sizeofarrey);
        for (i;i < sizeofarrey; i++)
            {
            printf ("Ingresa el valor %i \n",(i+1));
            scanf ("%i",&arrey[i]);
            }
            
            printf ("Los valores ingresados son ");
            
        for (n;n < sizeofarrey;n++)
            {
            printf ("%i ",arrey[n]);
            }                       
    }
}

//Aqui esta la funcion del factorial
long factorial (int x){
    if (x <= 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return x*factorial(x-1);
    }
}

//Aqui estaria la funcion de suma
int suma (){
    
    }
}
```

Agradecería enormemente cualquier orientación o ayuda que me puedan dar.

Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 3):

> hasta el momento entiendo que lo que debo hacer es crear un arreglo en el que el usuario ingrese cuantos números quiere sumar

Nada más lejos de la realidad... no te están pidiendo que guardes un array sino que sumes todas las entradas... es decir, solo necesitas dos variables:

- Un contador para saber cuándo tienes que dejar de pedir valores
- Una variable para almacenar el total

El algoritmo puede ser tan sencillo como:

- Si `n > 0`

  - pedir un número
  - sumarlo al total
  - Invocar la función recursiva
- En caso contrario

  - Salimos de la función

O, dicho con código:

```
int sumar(int n)
{
  int total = 0;

  if( n > 0 )
  {
    int numero;
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    total = numero + sumar(n-1);
  }

  return total;
}
```

O incluso podríamos simplificar el código aún más, ya que la variable `numero` es totalmente prescindible:

```
int sumar(int n)
{
  int total = 0;

  if( n > 0 )
  {
    scanf("%d", &total);
    total += sumar(n-1);
  }

  return total;
}
```

Así, para obtener el total de 5 números tendríamos que hacer la siguiente llamada:

```
int total = sumar(5);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, no se porque me metí la idea de que tenia que crear un array para hacer que mi "caso base" usara el numero de elementos del array para controlar el ciclo, parece que solo me estaba complicando mucho las cosas, nuevamente te agradezco mucho el apoyo